# WPF UserControl Data Binding performance

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I hope someone can help me with this one:

I created a WPF user control (call it MainControl) that use a couple of other user controls (UserControlA and UserControlB). Those 2 User Controls bind to Dependency Properties created in my  MainControl.xaml.cs class (MainControlDependencyProperty1 to 3). Those DP (in many cases) are bound to DP from the ViewModel. The following code illustrates this:

```
<StackPanel>

    <doesntmatter:UserControlA
        Property1="{Binding Path=MainControlProperty1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MainControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=OneWay}"
        Property2="{Binding Path=MainControlProperty2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MainControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    />

    <doesntmatter:UserControlB
        Property2="{Binding Path=MainControlProperty2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MainControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Property3="{Binding Path=MainControlProperty3, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type views:MainControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Mode=TwoWay}"
    />

</StackPanel>
```

Doing that I have a self-contained control that can be reused in several different parts of my application. I just drag it to the AXML, bind the proper DPs and life is good (I don’t store any data on it). The UserControlsA and B are also used separately from the MainControl in several other places.
It is all working fine but I would like to improve the performance so I have a couple of questions:

1 – Is it the proper way to bind the UserControlsA and B to my MainControl? I want it to be completely independent of my ViewModel. I know that DP is the method of choice to do the data binding in WPF but I am not sure if I am doing this on the best possible way (and fastest). I made it work once and followed the recipe…

2 – There are situations where I want the UserControlB to not be used at all. I make it invisible but the bindings and everything else in the control is still being executed when the DP in the ViewModel are updated. Is there an easy and painless way to disable the DP or the entire control so I can eliminate the overhead? (this.Disable=true; do not do it). I want the UserControlB DP’s to behave like they do not exist…

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes its the proper way to bind your elements together inside VisualTree. Here is an example directly from Microsoft. If you google ListView you can find a MSDN link to this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <!-- ListBox has a property called GridView and GridView is futhermore a class that has a property called Columns -->
    <!-- Within this setter you search your way up the visual tree till you find the colums of GridView. Then you bind those columns to yours -->
    <Setter Property="Columns" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=GridView.Columns}"
    ...
</Style>
```

In this example the inner controls of the ListView called ListViewItems (which later present rows filled with data and separated in different columns) binds its way up the visual tree to figure out what columns are set by user.

2) If you dont want to use it and you dont want the binding to be updated while collapsed then why making the efford to initalize it at all. The collapsed state of a control means its not visible but the updates are still received in case you wish to display the control at some certain point of time. With updates I mean the bindings to the data, width and height and other  necessary information.

Simply dont intialize the control at beginning but when needed inject a newly intialalized instance of it to the StackPanel. Its called `UI Virtualization`. And its used very often inside ListBoxes. Even though you may have 10 000 items of data, ListBox will only initalize 14 ListBoxItems controls because those are visible to you. Later when you start scrolling, the ListBox will destory or load more/less.

*PS: If you want to improve your performance first measure the behavior of your application with a performance profiler. Maybe you wont need to improve anything. Or maybe you will need to buy a new computer. Who knows, the profiler does. :PP*